# Firebase Deploy - No 'exports' main defined in firebase/package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Every time I run 'firebase deploy' I get this error message:

> Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in /Users/ghaith/Desktop/FacilityManagement/fm_back/functions/node_modules/firebase/package.json

I've tried reinstalling npm modules, I updated everything as well!

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const app = require("express")();
admin.initializeApp();

const config = {...};

const firebase = require("firebase");
firebase.initializeApp(config);

app.get("/requests", (req, res) => {
    admin
        .firestore()
        .collection("requests")
        .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
        .get()
        .then((data) => {
            let requests = [];
            data.forEach((doc) => {
                requests.push({
                    requestID: doc.id,
                    fname: doc.data().fname,
                    email: doc.data().email,
                    desc: doc.data().desc,
                    issue: doc.data().issue,
                    address: doc.data().address,
                });
            });
            return res.json(requests);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));
});
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with Firebase Cli v11.0!

Can you check the version and try to use Firebase Cli v10.8 for now.

It has some breaking changes with `ext:dev:emulators:start` and `ext:dev:emulators:exec` preview commands. Hence creating that problem.

Comment: im using, firebase v9.8, firebase admin v10.2

Comment: I am sorry I was late on reply ! Have you checked your codebase for proper imports ? I had the same problem but for me it fixed with imports correction! Since >v9 the imports are moved

Comment: no worries, which imports exactly are you talking about?

Comment: So when importing like this, you must be careful to import from proper locations.

_const { initializeApp} = require('firebase-admin/app')_
So for me i was having issue when i was importing the FieldValue like so, 
Also _const {FieldValue} = require("firebase-admin")_
I went to the docs [https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node] and fixed the imports. 

try to correct your imports and see. My version of functions and admin are here.
_"firebase-admin": "^10.2.0"_,
 _"firebase-functions": "^3.21.2"_