# ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED with firebase-admin 11.0.0 and firebase-functions 3.21.2

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, node-modules, package.json, firebase-admin

I'm trying to update to the most recent versions of `firebase-admin` (11.0.0) and `firebase-functions` (3.21.2). I'm using `firebase-tools` 11.1.0. I get this error when try to deploy my functions:

```
Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/myuser/Documents/myproject/node_modules/firebase-functions/package.json
```

I've seen similar errors in StackOverflow like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72406512/firebase-function-failed-to-load-function-definition-from-source-error-solution) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72296610/firebase-deploy-no-exports-main-defined-in-firebase-package-json) but this error is slightly different. The problem is not in `firebase` or `firebase-admin` dependencies but with `firebase-functions`.

Using `firebase-functions` 3.14.1 works (I get some warnings though) but I'd like to update to the latest version so I can hopefully get rid of warnings and get the latest updates.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Fixed my error by replacing `import {getAuth} from 'firebase-admin/lib/auth';` with `import {auth} from 'firebase-admin';`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error described, the problem was that I had imports referencing the lib folder of firebase-functions like this:

```
import { HttpsError } from 'firebase-functions/lib/providers/https'
...
throw new HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'An error')
```

The problem was gone after removing all of them and replacing with something like the following:

```
import { https } from 'firebase-functions'
...
throw new https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'An error')
```

The first approach worked until 3.14.1. Above that, it looks like we can't reference the lib folder in the from. Not ideal because I wanted to avoid the namespace when using these types, but at least it works.

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation, we can find a [warning](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#set-up-node.js-and-the-firebase-cli) to constantly update the firebase-functions sdk. The warning is:

> In many cases, new features and bug fixes are available only with the
> latest version of the Firebase CLI and the firebase-functions SDK.
> It's a good practice to frequently update both the Firebase CLI and
> the SDK with these commands inside the functions folder of your
> Firebase project:
>
> ```
> npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save npm
> install -g firebase-tools
> ```

These could be the main causes for this error message. As you haven't provided any code.

**Additonally**, it might be conflicting with the firebase-admin 11.0 version. This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/1147) claims firebase-admin 11.0 does not support firebase-functions version 3.21.2. But it succeeds with firebase-admin 10.0 and firebase-functions version 3.21.2.

I’d suggest using firebase-admin 10.0 and firebase-functions version 3.21.2.

Comment: I saw a comment like this one in a similar post but I'm not sure what I should do! All of these three dependencias were the latest ones so, in practice, it's like I had run the command you described. I didn't provide code but I explicitly mentioned the involved versions. Do you think there might be conflicts with other dependencies?

Comment: It might be conflicting with the firebase-admin 11.0 version. This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/1147) claims firebase-admin 11.0 does not support firebase-functions version 3.21.2. But it succeeds with firebase-admin 10.0 and firebase-functions version 3.21.2.

I’d suggest using firebase-admin 10.0 and firebase-functions version 3.21.2.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using firebase-admin 10.3.0 as you suggested to avoid the warning.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to how you are importing in your application. I was putting extra slash at the end which is giving me the same error.

From

```
const admin   = require('firebase-admin/');
```

To

```
const admin   = require('firebase-admin');
```